# Angular CLI custom builder

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-builder, angular-devkit

Angular CLI 6 introduced a new concept of builders (aka Architect Targets).
There are a couple of [prebuilt builders](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/tree/master/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src) that come with [`@angular-devkit/build_angular`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-devkit/build-angular), but unfortunately there is no documentation that explains how to create your own builder.

How do I create my own builder (for example to modify the underlying webpack configuration)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Update:

For Angular 8+ read [this](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/angular-cli-under-the-hood-builders-demystified-v2-e73ee0f2d811) AngularInDepth article.

### For Angular 6 and 7:

The full article can be found [here](https://medium.com/dailyjs/angular-cli-6-under-the-hood-builders-demystified-f0690ebcf01).

For the sake of simplicity I assume that the new builder is implemented in Typescript, but it can be implemented in pure JavaScript as well.

### Implementation:

1. Create a directory for your custom builders (for example *custom-builders*) in the root of your project (or alternatively install it as a [local npm module](https://medium.com/@arnaudrinquin/build-modular-application-with-npm-local-modules-dfc5ff047bcc))
2. Inside the directory create a file called *builders.json*, *index.ts* and *package.json* that contains `builders` entry pointing to *builders.json*
3. Inside *custom-builders* create a directory for the builder you want to implement (say, *custom-builders/my-cool-builder*
4. Add *index.ts*, *schema.json* and *schema.d.ts* to *my-cool-builder* directory
5. Populate *schema.json* with the schema of your builder options. See an example [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/browser/schema.json).
6. Define your *schema.d.ts* according to the *schema.json* you defined. See an example [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/browser/schema.d.ts).
7. Implement your builder in *my-cool-builder/index.ts*. The builder has to implement the following interface:

   ```
   export interface Builder<OptionsT> {
     run(builderConfig: BuilderConfiguration<Partial<OptionsT>>):  Observable<BuildEvent>;
   }
   ```

   While `BuildEvent` is this:

   ```
   export interface BuildEvent {
     success: boolean;
   }
   ```

   `BuilderConfiguration` is this:

   ```
   export interface BuilderConfiguration<OptionsT = {}> {
     root: Path;
     sourceRoot?: Path;
     projectType: string;
     builder: string;
     options: OptionsT;
   }
   ```

   And `OptionsT` is the interface you defined for your builder options in *schema.d.ts*

   You can use [`browser`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/browser/index.ts) architect target as a reference.
8. Once implemented, add your builder to *builders.json*:

   ```
   {
     "$schema": "@angular-devkit/architect/src/builders-schema.json",
     "builders": {
       "cool-builder": {
         "class": "./my-cool-builder",
         "schema": "./my-cool-builder/schema.json",
         "description": "My cool builder that builds things up"
       }
     }
   }
   ```

### Usage:

In your *angular.json*:

```
    "architect": {
        ...
        "build": {
                  "builder": "./custom-builders:cool-builder"
                  "options": {
                         your options here
                  }
```

### Example

For the full example check out this library: https://github.com/meltedspark/angular-builders

Comment: I struggled to get this working with a locally defined builder so I created a repo demonstrating it here: https://github.com/Roaders/angular-electron-chrome/tree/js-custom-builder. unfortunately I can't get it to work with a typescript builder (without an extra compile step)

Comment: What is your struggle exactly?

Comment: @Roaders yeah I suppose the CLI is tooling is not set up to auto compile _if_ the class builder is a typescript file?

Answer (score 1):

For those who use Angular 8 and higher, builders API is now officially supported and documented: https://angular.io/guide/cli-builder

It has a lot of changes compared to the previous version, so migration from Angular 7 to 8 might become complicated if you are using undocumented Architect API.

Here's a nice article to get started: https://blog.angular.io/introducing-cli-builders-d012d4489f1b

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it and I'm not quite sure, but this concept might be solution.

`architect.build.builder` uses some Angular schematics in order to perform build process. You can create your own schematics which uses/inherits regular build schematics with additional logic that you want to implement.