# How to run nestjs-console commands in context of Angular / nx workspace

Tags: angular, angular-cli, nestjs, nrwl, nrwl-nx

I have a NestJS application as part of an Angular / Nx workspace.

Within the nest application I'm using `nestjs-console` to run commands (e.g. to load fixture data).

Per the [nestjs-console docs](https://github.com/Pop-Code/nestjs-console) this involves:

1. Creating a `console.ts` file
2. Adding a script in package.json like `"console:dev": "ts-node --project apps/api/tsconfig.console.json apps/api/src/console.ts"`
3. Calling it, e.g. with `npm run console:dev -- --help`

Now I have used Nx to create a [lib of shared code](https://nx.dev/web/tutorial/07-share-code) between applications.

This works well for commands under Angular CLI (`test`; `serve` etc.), but the nestjs-console task understandably fails with:

> Error: Cannot find module '@my-workspace/my-lib'

So the question is how to bring the nestjs-console command under the control of Angular CLI (or run NestJS commands in some other way).

I feel it should be possible to add a custom task to `angular.json` which uses an existing builder and then somehow points to the console command. (I don’t feel like I need a [custom builder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51131493/1450420), but I could be wrong about that).

I’m stuck because I’m not so familiar with this environment, and [angular.json workspace config](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config).

Any help is appreciated, be it:

- Advice on approaches
- Examples I can copy
- Specific pointers

**EDIT**

I tried using the NestJS [Application Context](https://docs.nestjs.com/application-context) directly, (rather than via `nestjs-console`) and per this [blog post](https://medium.com/the-crowdlinker-chronicle/seeding-databases-using-nestjs-cd6634e8efc5) running it with `ts-node`.

This has the same problems as before. I believe this issue is something to do with how ts-node handles paths in tsconfg.

If I change the way the shared code is imported from:

```js
import { HeadwordDto } from '@my-workspace/my-lib';
```

To:

```js
import { HeadwordDto } from '../../../../../../libs/my-lib/src';
```

Then everything works, but tslint complains with "library imports must start with @my-workspace/ (nx-enforce-module-boundaries)." I can see how this defeats the point of Nx.

Alternatively, dealing with what I think is the [paths issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10866) looks a bit hairy and involves tools like [tspath](https://github.com/duffman/tspath#readme) or [module-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias). It also does not benefit from Nx goodness.

I have now added a new [Architect target](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#configuring-builder-targets) to angular.json which is just like the `build` target (using the `@nrwl/node:build` builder), except that is builds the desired application context:

```json
"build-console": {
  "builder": "@nrwl/node:build",
  "options": {
    "main": "apps/api/src/console.ts",      // build console application context
    "outputPath": "different/output/path",  // can run alongside app
    ...
  }
},
```

After this is built then it can be [run via node](https://github.com/Pop-Code/nestjs-console#usage):

```
node ./different/output/path/main.js –help
```

**EDIT 2**

Building on the approach above, it's also possible to use the [execute builder](https://nx.dev/angular/api/node/builders/execute) to build the console application context continually in a separate terminal window:

```json
"serve-console": {
  "builder": "@nrwl/node:execute",
  "options": {
    "buildTarget": "api:build-console",
    "port": 7778,
    "args": ["--help"]
  }
},
```

From here I guess the next step could be to make the console application context into a separate app, with its own project in angular.json, and just pull in the needed code. Starting to feel like the Nx team are about 58 steps ahead of me ;-)

Not sure if this is the best solution, but it works.  As before, any advice appreciated!

**EDIT 3**

To expand on this, in response to @Digitrance's question. The approach I ended up using was:

*angular.json*

```js
{
    ...
    "api": {
      ...
      "architect": {
        ...
        "build-console": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/node:build",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/apps/api-console",
            "main": "apps/api/src/console.ts",
            "tsConfig": "apps/api/tsconfig.app.json"
          }
        },
        "serve-console": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/node:execute",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "api:build-console",
            "port": 7778,
            "args": ["--help"]
          }
        },
```

*/my-repo/apps/api/src/console.ts*

```js
import { BootstrapConsole } from 'nestjs-console';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

const bootstrap = new BootstrapConsole({
  module: AppModule,
  useDecorators: true
});
bootstrap.init().then(async app => {
  try {
    await app.init();
    await bootstrap.boot();
    process.exit(0);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Error', e);
    process.exit(1);
  }
});
```

And then commands to run the console:

```
ng run api:build-console
ng run api:serve-console

node ./dist/apps/api-console/main.js --help
node ./dist/apps/api-console/main.js myCommand
```

(Note that `api` was the name of my app).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Like you, I had trouble setting this up. My error boiled down to syntax errors, which according to some issues at ts-node github had to do with node not being able to read the imports properly because it was commonjs syntax. My solution was as followed:

1. Add the tsconfig.console.json next to the tsconfig.app.json in your nx application.
2. Make sure the tsconfig.console.json contains `"module": "commonjs"` inside the `"compilerOptions"`. Other than that I copied tsconfig.app.json.
3. In the package.json add the following line: `"console:dev": "ts-node --project apps/api/tsconfig.console.json -r tsconfig-paths/register apps/api/src/console.ts"` to your scripts.

Hope it helps you or anyone else.

Comment: Thanks for this.  My feeling in the end was that `ts-node` in the nestjs-console docs was a red herring.  One of the features of Angular CLI / nx is that it gives lots of ways of building TypeScript files into JS. I ended up doing the builds with new architect targets in angular.json, and not using ts-node.

Comment: @DerekHill Could you please share a code sample of your solution?

Comment: Ok @Digitrance.  I have edited my question to include more sample code.  Hope this helps.